# Require not working properly, always lead to an error

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ether, dapps

There is a login page and register page in my dapp based on refer and earn concept to authenticate and authorize user respectively..Login part is working fine, but when I try to register a new account into blockchain with 0.05 ether fees, metamask pops up and shows ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code..When I check on etherscan, I got User already exists error instead.No matter which address I use, the error remain same.

```
 uint public lastUserId = 2;

 struct User {
    uint id;
    address referrer;
    uint partnerCount;
    bool isRegistered;
}

//function isUserExists(address _userAddress) public view returns(bool){
    //   return users[_userAddress].id != 0;
    //}

 function userRegisteration(address _userAddress, address _referAddress) private returns(bool) {
    require(msg.value == 0.05 ether, 'registeration cost 0.05');
    // require(!isUserExists(_userAddress), "User already exists");
    // require(isUserExists(_referAddress), "Referrer doesn't exist");
    
    require(!users[_userAddress].isRegistered, "User already exists"); //The error I got
    require(users[_userAddress].isRegistered, "Referrer doesn't exist");
    
    User memory user = User({
        id: lastUserId,
        referrer: _referAddress,
        partnerCount: 0,
        isRegistered: true
    });
    
    users[_userAddress] = user;
    users[_userAddress].referrer = _referAddress;
    users[_referAddress].partnerCount++;
    lastUserId++;
    
    emit registerSuccess(_userAddress, _referAddress);
    return true
}

function registeration(address _referAddress) external payable {
    userRegisteration(msg.sender, _referAddress);
}
```

Web3js

```
 contract.registeration(
        $("#refer_id").val(),
        { value: web3.toWei(0.05), gasPrice: 98e9 },
        function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            $(".tx").show();
            $(".transaction_err").text(err.message);
            return false;
          }
        });
```

)

**The response I got in the console is**

```
  Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x8338fb44f94cef337879b07ebf8251f99b3c6238489e0c2e10d903cf921a0d1c",
  "blockNumber": 7427013,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 22838,
  "from": "0x8a9bbe43c28a82596f7ae4cff80377a7c8e0c25c",
  "gasUsed": 22838,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x2d99d6db85b012bdd3ced1c21fc025847c6c2694",
  "transactionHash": "0x07e03803ede8a172db5cbe27f3aafead9668af0a6e9fbe7804802b1bf0c5a6b4",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "events": {}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you deployed that exact solidity code? Perhaps the user is registered in the constructor. Did you try calling registration with another account? The registration appears to be fine, if there's an error it is somewhere else.

Comment: @Ismael yes, I'm sure, I've deployed  the exace code...No, User is not registered in constructor..owner registeration is in constructor function..Now when I remove those three requires, the result seem to be fine..However, I want those condition to check before register...

Comment: Are you really, really sure? Perhaps compilation failed and you didn't notice, then deployed an old version. There's a mistake where `_userAddress` is used for both user and referrer address, but that shouldn't cause "User already exists" error. After fixing that problem the contract works as expected in remix with solc 0.6.12. Which solc are you using?